# URL rewriting with UrlRewritingNet fails with a + char in the URL

Tags: .net, iis-7, url-rewriting, umbraco

I'm using UrlRewritingNet in Umbraco to do some basic URL rewriting of product and category URLs. Everything is fine on my local machine (Visual Studio dev-webserver) and on our internal development server (Window Server 2008 with ISS 7, 32 bit). But it fails on the production server, which is Window Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7 (64 bit). The symptom is that the rewrite rule is not triggered. The server simply gives me an 404 error.

The rewriting rule looks like this:

```
<add name="CategoryRewrite"
     virtualUrl="^/products/(.*)/(.*).aspx"
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
     destinationUrl="~/default.aspx?umbPage=1&amp;maincategory=$1&amp;subcategory=$2"
     ignoreCase="true"/>
```

The URL looks like the following - this doesn't work:

```
http://example.net/products/category+name/sub+category.aspx
```

If I change the URL to the following it works in all 3 environments:

```
http://example.net/products/category%20name/sub%20category.aspx
```

It is clear that the regex in the virtualUrl attribute fails when the + is used for the space character. But I must admit, that I can figure out why the regex fails only on the Windows 2008 R2 server.

I'm looking for insights on what differences between the Windows Server 2008 R2 and the other 2 environments. What should I look for?

I have confirmed that the System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll is the same version on the servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the IIS7 request filter rejects URLs containing + characters. The solution is add the following to you Web.config:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <security>
   <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
  </security>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For further details: http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2007/12/17/iis7-rejecting-urls-containing.aspx

A coworker got the bright idea to run the website on his own IIS. And then the error was further defined as a 404.11, and from there on a solution was simple.

Answer (score 0):

That seems strange to me because your regex matches also '+' characters. Maybe the problem is because of the first character in the regex, beginning of string '^' that you are using. Maybe on the production server you get an absolute URL and on your dev environment server a relative URL passed into the rewriting module.

Comment: Strange indeed. Nice theory about the absolute URL, but I will have to shoot it down. The regex works also on the production server, just not with a + character in the URL. It seems as it is never routed into the UrlRewritingNet.